# Let user add item to combobox collection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, collections, combobox

I want to let the user permanently add to the combobox collection if something is missing. I know it's possible if you connect to a database or put the collection in a text file.

I was wondering if the collection is entered manually in Visual Studio is it possible for the user to add to this collection?

Comment: No, the custom item would have to come from an external source: a file, database, etc.

Comment: Do you want to post this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the answer is no.

Any custom entries to the items collection at runtime would require you to have that information in a file or a database or a registry setting.  Then when opening the program, you would have to read those items from the source and add them into your control's item collection again.